# SQL code generation question, group by and aggregates

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm working on a web application that lets a user design ad-hoc queries against an employee database. The queries are designed in an AJAX web based interface where the user specifies groups of crtieria that get intersected together, i'm trying to add functionality to also allow the user introduce date relationships between crtieria. For example, here's a sample (problematic) generated code for a query that says "Give me all employees that had at least 3 audits 150+ days after they started on the job"

```
select * FROM  
    (   
        SELECT employee_id 
               , max(employee_start_date) employee_start_date  
        from employees 
        where employee_salary_type in (55, 66, 77) 
    group by employee_id having count(*) >= 1
   ) employee_criteria_1,
  ( 
   SELECT employee_id 
             ,max(audit_date) audit_date  
       from employees 
   where job_audit_id in (5, 6, 7)  
   -- They had at least 3 audits
  group by employee_id having count(*) >= 3     
) employee_criteria_2
WHERE 
     employee_criteria_1.employee_id = employee_criteria_2.employee_id 
  -- The audits must have happened at least 150 days after employee's start date
   and   employee_criteria_2.audit_date > employee_criteria_1.employee_start_date + 150
```

As you notice, each criteria from the UI gets generated into a SQL `SELECT` block, the all are intersected together. Here's my problem:

The query above checks whether the employee had at least 3 audits, and the last audit `MAX` occurs 150 days after start date INSTEAD of `the 3 audits occur 150+ after start date`.

You might ask, "well, why do you have a max(audit_date) statement then?" The reason is that I need to have an aggregate function in order for the group by to work (the group here is generated out of the "occurs at least 3 times" high-level query criteria).

So, what can I add to this code (without much changes, cause i'd like to keep this code generation mechanism) so that i'm now checking that all those 3 occurrences/audits happen 150+ days after (instead of only the max one)??

Thanks!

Comment: so wouldn't that be the MIN(audit_date) then? (if the "oldest" one of 3 occurred 150+ days after the emp start date, then all 3 fit that bill as well)

Comment: True for this case, but also I would the code generation template to be flexible as the first criteria dates could be something other than employee start date. Is there a way to capture the dates of each of those audit occurrences within this query?

Comment: also, what if an audit occurred 2 days after they started and then 4 audits occurred 150+ days after? the MIN would capture the one 2 days after which would return no results (even though there are 4 audits later on)

Comment: why not then just remove the group by and having count(1) > 3 check from the 2nd inline select (output ALL audit dates here), and then do your criteria check in the outer where clause (as a filter)?  ie, you seem to do some of the criteria check in the inline select (count >= 3) and try to do remainder in where clause

Comment: It seems like your database model is not normalized, maybe I'm wrong but the audits should be a different table and then you could rewrite the queries in

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to look into [window functions](http://www.orafaq.com/node/55), and possibly the [having](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause rather than the where clause.

Comment: Just started looking into, thanks for the tip! Do you have any suggestion how this could effectively be applied into the case above?

Comment: Usually, databases only allow window functions in the select/order by clauses, so this means using a subquery, and then filtering the results. (Note that this will invariably lead to a full table scan unless you insert the where clauses in the subselect.)